# Fiber restart callback issue

Tags: node.js, node-fibers, fibers

I would like to stop (gracefully or not) a function run via fibers.
Fibers have throwInto() and reset() methods for doing that.
But when I use it, my callback restart.
Do you know why ?

Here a little example for what I have done.

Code:

```
Fiber = require("fibers")
f = Fiber(function(){
  try{
    console.log("First Wait 1000 sec");
    fiber = Fiber.current
    setTimeout(function(){
      fiber.run()
    }, 1000);
    Fiber.yield()
    console.log("End of first wait");
    console.log("Second Wait 1000 sec");
    fiber = Fiber.current
    setTimeout(function(){
      fiber.run()
    }, 1000);
    Fiber.yield()
    console.log("End of second wait");
  }catch(err){
    console.log("Got an error");
    console.log(err);
    console.log("Third Wait 1000 sec");
    fiber = Fiber.current
    setTimeout(function(){
      fiber.run()
    }, 1000);
    Fiber.yield()
    console.log("End of third wait");
  }
  return 0;
});

f.run();

setTimeout(function(){
  f.throwInto(new Error("End gracefully"));
  //f.reset(); //End brutally
}, 500);
```

Output :

```
First Wait 1000 sec
Got an error
[Error: End gracefully]
Third Wait 1000 sec
End of third wait
First Wait 1000 sec
End of first wait
Second Wait 1000 sec
End of second wait
```

Comment: Alter many test, I found one solution.

I rethrow the error in the catch part. It's ugly but it's work.

Do you have any better solutions ?